# Deserialize list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I Use [JsonConvert](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize an object and save it in a database.
 This is a sample of the serialized string that I saved in database:

`[{"matId":"1","value":"44"},{"matId":"2","value":"55"},{"matId":"4","value":"77"}]`

Now when I get this string from database which has a lot of backslashes like this:

`"[{\"matId\":\"1\",\"value\":\"44\"},{\"matId\":\"2\",\"value\":\"55\"},{\"matId\":\"4\",\"value\":\"77\"}]"`

And for this reason I can't `Deserialize` it.

`.Replace("\\","")` method doesn't create any affect on this. I don't know why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `JsonConvert.Deserialize` method.

Your `json` string is wrapped within square brackets `([])`, hence it is interpreted as array. Therefore, you need to `deserialize` it to `type` collection of one `class`, for example let's call it `MyClass`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int matId { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is `Deserialize` method.

```
var results=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);
```

Comment: I get an error when I Deserialize , `Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'my type'  because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.`

Answer (score 2):

Backslashes represent serialized object. 
You need to deserialize your List object.
You can try using Generics:

```
public List<T> Deserialize<T>(string path)
{
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when looking at json strings as you are debugging. In Visual Studio it needs to format the value into a string. To do that it will add " so that it can process it when actually the value does not contain them. That is why the replace does not work.