# Deserialize JSON Data into a List in C#

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization

After hours of searching and trying, can someone please be so kind and help me solving this following simple problem:

I have the following JSON-String:

```
[
    {
        "key": 1234,
    },
    {
        "key": 9876,
    }
]
```

How can I read this JSON and write all values into a List?

Had many attempts so far, but please see following code:

```
List<int> content = new List<int>;
var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
```

First try:

```
foreach(var key in obj)
{
    content.Add((int)obj["key"]);
}
```

Other try:

```
var token = obj.SelectToken("key");

foreach(var item in token)
{
   content.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(item.value));
}
```

Or something this way?

```
foreach(var key in obj)
{
    content.Add(Int32.Parse(obj.GetValue("key").ToString()));
}
```

Trying to run the last attempt, I get following error message:
`Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray.`
Even if the JSON looks like the following:

```
[{\"key\":9999},{\"key\":9876}]
```

Would be very happy for every answer.

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize list of objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415938/deserialize-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

It can be done in the following way:

```
    List<string> yourList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(YourJson).ToList();
```

NOTE: It can only be saved as a list of strings , but can be called with: `yourList.YourKeyName`.

Comment: I added the following:
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json).ToList();
Unfortunately he says:
"object" does not contain a Definition for "ToList" (Maybe a using-directive is missing)"

Comment: Make sure your function is a `List<string>` aswell.

Comment: I rechecked it again. Yes, my function is List<string> as well: private List<string> getKey(string ip){List<string> content = new List<string>();var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(ip,path)); using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse){using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())){var json = reader.ReadToEnd();content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json).ToList();}}return content;}

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want but you could also create a specified class for your json.
The following class represents your json string.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int key { get; set; }
}
```

You could then deserialise your json string as follows:

```
string json=reader.ReadToEnd();

List<RootObject> myobs=JsonConvert.DeserialiseObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

You can then do stuffs with the list.

```
foreach(var ob in myobs){
Console.WriteLine(ob.key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on to what @bolkay said, you need to define your object:

```
public class KeyClass
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
}
```

and then if your JSON is in a variable called jsString for example

```
        List<int> content = new List<int>();
        var keys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyClass>>(jsString);
        foreach (var item in keys)
        {
            content.Add(item.Key);
        }
```