# Newtonsoft deserialize Array to class with properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Consuming an external service where they decided to provide an object as an array where each property is on a fixed position. Like

```
{
    "persons" : [
        ["Luck", "Lucky", 28],
        ["Joe", "Dalton", 30],
        ["Jack", "Dalton", 28],
        ["William", "Dalton", 26],
        ["Averell", "Dalton", 24]
    ]
}
```

I would like to deserialize this to a List of Person.

```
var persons =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person[]>(json);

class Person {
      public string FirstName {get; set; }
      public string LastName {get; set; }
      public int Age{get; set; }
}
```

Is there an easy way (property annotation) to do this, or will it come down to write a custom serialiser?

Since most answers are missing the essence of the question.

This would have been easy if

```
  {
    "persons" : [
        { 
             "FirstName" :  "Luck", 
             "LastName" : "Lucky", 
             "Age" : 28 
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

But that is not the case.

Comment: I presume you mis-copied your example as it's not valid JSON (persons needs to be "persons").

Answer (score 2):

You can do it very easy and simple with this:

```
PersonList personObject = new PersonList();


public class PersonList
{
    public List<Person> persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Age{ get; set; }
}

personObject  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonList>(YourResponseContent);
```

And then the `personObject` items will have the values of the Response.

The `MainList` have to have the same name with your item in the Response. This is important to read the `JSON` Response.

Comment: will fail with Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Person' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Good fix, take an upvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

`persons` property is array of arrays of strings. Try to deserialize to `List<List<string>>` first

```cs
public class Root
{
    public List<List<string>> persons { get; set; }
}
```

and then convert it to list of `List<Person>` using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) method

```cs
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
var persons = root.persons
    .Select(l => new Person { FirstName = l[0], LastName = l[1], Age = int.Parse(l[2]) })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: root will not be an array of Person and therefor does not answer the question.

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen I've added a linq call to get a list of `Person` class

Comment: Hmm, you would deserialize it as is, and then map it to Person. Not the question but probably a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom json deserializer.

Try this:

```
public class PersonJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public class RootJson
    {
        public List<List<string>> Persons { get; set; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(jsonObject.Root.ToString());

        var persons = root.Persons
            .Select(p => new Person { FirstName = p[0], LastName = p[1], Age = int.Parse(p[2]) })
            .ToList();

        return persons;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And you can derserialize like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}

 var deserializedRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(yourJson, new PersonJsonConverter());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [Deserialize list of objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415938/deserialize-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp)

```
var results=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public class Root
{
    public List<List<Object>> persons { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
Root dsz = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(sz);
```

It will be deserialized to list of persons each person will have list of vars.

```
persons[0][0] = "Luck"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do something like that:

```
public class PersonObj
{
    public List<Person> persons {get;set;}
    public string FirstName { get { return persons.First(); }
    public string LastName { get { return return persons.Skip(1).First(); } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParsedList
    {
        public List<List<object>> persons { get; set; }
    }
    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

text is your JSON:

```
ParsedList list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParsedList>(text);

            List<Person> people = list.persons.Select(x => new Person()

            {
                FirstName = x[0].ToString(),
                LastName = x[1].ToString(),
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(x[2])
            }
            
            ).ToList();
```